# How to run Maven / JVM (e.g. Appium + Saucelabs / Selenium + Browserstack) Test Automation on Bitrise

Tags: maven, saucelabs, bitrise

Is it possible to run Java based test automation suite on Bitrise CI/CD?

Functionalities which I will be looking at:
 - Maven Runtime
 - String Parameters passing
 - Cucumber-JVM 
 - Connectivity to Cloud devices provider like  Browserstack(web) / Saucelabs(mobile)

Also, what kind of job will we need to set-up on Bitrise, for this purpose

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a Script step which calls a script inside your repository: (Path is relative to your repo)

[image: Picture of Script Step named Run Test Controller]

**Script Step:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex

bash ./scripts/bitrise/test_controller.sh
```

Inside the `test_controller.sh` we have logic which controls the other bash scripts to execute (can use ruby as well), which will we will then run maven in:

**test_controller.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex

if [[ "$SHOULD_RUN_SPECIFIC_TESTS" == "false" && "$SHOULD_RUN_RELEASE_TESTS" == "false" ]]; then
  if [[ $BITRISE_TRIGGERED_WORKFLOW_TITLE == "iOS-Appium" ]]; then
    echo "=> Executing run_develop_ios_tests.sh"
    bash ./scripts/bitrise/ios/run_develop_ios_tests.sh
    exit 0
  elif [[ $BITRISE_TRIGGERED_WORKFLOW_TITLE == "Android-Appium" ]]; then
    echo "=> Executing run_develop_android_tests.sh"
    bash ./scripts/bitrise/android/run_develop_android_tests.sh
    exit 0
  fi
fi
```

If we don't want to run specific tests, and not release, and the workflow that triggered this run is iOS-Appium, then we run execute `run_develop_ios_tests.sh`:

**run_develop_ios_tests.sh**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex

mvn clean test \
  -DplatformName=IOS \
  -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="${XML_FILES}" \
  -DIOS_DEVICE_NAME="${IOS_DEVICE_NAME}" \
  -DIOS_PLATFORM_VERSION="${IOS_PLATFORM_VERSION}" \
  -DSAUCE_USERNAME="${SAUCE_USERNAME}" \
  -DSAUCE_ACCESS_KEY="${SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY}"
```

The logic inside the test controller, is driven by env variables -- and so are the string params which guide our `mvn clean test` command.

Since we connect to SauceLabs remotely, we do not need any special agent for this. Just JDK and Maven, which are pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Bitrise definitely provides these functionality and can auto configure or recommend some solution while you're doing the project setup. If you'd need any help/guidance along the process contact the Bitrise support (via the onsite chat or email), they can help you with your specific setup :)

Comment: Viktor would know better for sure, but I thought Bitrise does not support identifying a plain Java project at this time or testing related (Appium/Selenium) for example. But one can add onto the open source project to implement detecting a project like this with the bitrise init command.